How can I sort a vector of floats in Rust?
If I have a couple of floating-point numbers and try to sort them like this:
fn main() {
    let mut nums: Vec<f64> = vec![0.53, 3.18, 4.783, 9.0, -1.2, 0.0];
    nums.sort();
    println!("{:?}", nums);
}

I get a compile error: "the trait bound f64: Ord is not satisfied".
How can I sort these numbers?

(I'm posting a question I already know the answer to in the hopes that it will help people in the future)

TLDR: do
nums.sort_by(f64::total_cmp);

The basic reason why Rust doesn't let you sort floating-point numbers is that NaN is weird. All comparisons involving a NaN return false, which can cause sorting algorithms to break (this is an issue in Python, for example). There's also the strange case of zero and negative zero, which are equal yet have different representations. Since Rust's design philosophy revolves around handling errors explicitly, you cannot use the sort() method on floats.
However, IEEE 754 does define a way to sort floating-point numbers which can handle any kind of NaN (there are many bit patterns which represent a NaN). The order is:

NaN (negative sign bit), in descending order of the significand bits
Negative infinity
All the negative numbers, in mathematical order
Negative zero
Positive zero
All the positive numbers, in mathematical order
Positive infinity
NaN (positive sign bit), in ascending order of the significand bits

To get this ordering, Rust offers the total_cmp method between all the float types. Therefore, your code can be fixed by doing:
fn main() {
    let mut nums: Vec<f64> = vec![0.53, 3.18, 4.783, 9.0, -1.2, 0.0];
    nums.sort_by(f64::total_cmp);
    println!("{:?}", nums);
}

(playground link)

Re “NaN (negative sign bit), in descending order of the mantissa bits”: After the sign bit, the IEEE 754-2019 totalOrder predicate specifies signaling +NaNs are less than quiet +NaNs, reversed for negative, and then the order is implementation-defined. (There are no mantissa bits since IEEE-754 floating-point representations have significands, not mantissas. “Mantissa” is an old word for the fractional part of a logarithm. Mantissas are logarithmic; significands are linear.) Also, there is further distinction for equal values that occur with decimal formats.

IEEE 754-2008 did say NaNs were ordered by “payload,” but that was not well defined.

@EricPostpischil Yes I agree that IEEE 754 has some nuances with regard to NaN, but if you look at the actual source code for total_cmp (https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/f64.rs.html#1350) it sorts purely off of bit order and there is no implementation-defined behaviour — so I'm not sure whether this would be in the scope of my answer. Thanks for the notes!
